# Is there a way to retrieve in OpenGL all the generated names regarding a specific identifier?

Tags: opengl

At the moment we are tracking objects generation at the application level, but I'd like to drop this and delegate it (if possible).

So, my question is if there is a way to list all the opengl objects/identifiers currently generated/created.

For example, I'd like to see how many textures names there are at one specific moment generated.

I couldn't find anything around, so my guess is no, but I'd like to be sure about that.

For a moment (I swear) I thought to loop over all the possible values and then `glIs*`, but this is silly of course

[Wiki OpenGL_Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Object)

Comment: Maybe wrap `glGen*`/`glDelete*` functions with macros that keep track of created objects?

Comment: That's kind of what we are doing

Comment: @elect: Having object tracking in place is a good thing. It means (among other things) that it will be far easier to port to modern APIs like Vulkan or DX12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You created those objects, so you are expected to know what they are. The `glIs*` date back to the days when you could unilaterally declare that some particular integer value was an object simply by binding it. So it was (in theory) useful to ask if that particular integer had already been used as an object. But in core OpenGL, where objects *must* be allocated by the implementation, the `glIs*` functions aren't particularly useful.